# Gmail Filtering

Tags: gmail-filters

I have Gmail filters set up to label incoming mail based on the the company name in the subject, and it is working just fine (For my case they are marked as read and labeled). If however the subject, in addition to the company name contains an additional keyword, I would like it to remain in my Primary box, starred, and left as unread.

Since Gmail doesn't filter in order, if I search for the additional keyword, it will leave the message as unread, and starred, however it is also placed in the appropriate label section. How can I prevent it from going in the labeled area?

Comment: Can you share the filter queries you've been using for the two cases? I suspect you may have forgotten to exclude the second keyboard from the first filter.